# Reading OCaml's Marshall Files in Java or Python

Tags: java, json, serialization, ocaml

Is there a way to read OCaml's default serialization output (.marshall) in other programming languages, like Java?

I am aware of thrift/protobuf, both of which do support seralization for OCaml types. There a couple of options that help serializing the types to JSONs-- Anton Lavrik's excellent [Piqi-lib](http://piqi.org/doc/ocaml/) and Martin Jambon's super [Yojson](http://mjambon.com/yojson.html). Generated JSONs are too huge (think GiBs), and seem ineffective, and we really don't want serialization/de-serialization to be as heavy a bottleneck + space inefficient. Not to mention the RAM usage!

Is there something else that I haven't explored which would let me read OCaml's default marshall output as-is in Java or Python?

Comment: One of the problems is cycles, which can be tricky or impossible to restore depending on the language. Assuming pure data (no functions) without cycles, python may be a fine target because it is untyped; Java looks impossible unless you translate OCaml type definitions into Java classes (note that atdj can do that, but the data format is json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can use `piqi` lib to serialize to protobuf. That will be much more efficient in space and time. Also, take a look at cap'n'proto. It is available for all three, and is very fast (faster than protobuf). Other option, would be to use Janestreet `bin_prot`, but this will require you to write parsers in Python and Java, since it is only available to OCaml, currently.

And of course, it is impossible to read marshaled data in languages other then OCaml, since it is at least non-documented.